# Best practices for managing optional interface properties in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an interface with the following properties:

```
interface ISchedule {
  date: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime?: string;
}
```

now the **endTime** property here is optional because it is undefined when an object is created using the interface. It is defined later on in the codebase. Once it is defined, i have to pass the object to a function where the type of the object is ISchedule.

Now inside the function, if i try to use the **endTime** property, i get:

> "Object is possibly undefined"

Now there are two ways to handle this:

1. add an if check
2. use ! to bypass null/undefined checks

In my opinion, adding an if check around the property is redundant/dangerous since i am sure that the property will always exist/has to exist in the respective function. The function's behavior will change if the property does not exist.

However, a few team mates disagree with this and insist on using the if check.

I wanted to know what are the best practices for handing optional properties in Typescript and what is the ideal way to handle this specific situation as this is occurring in alot of places in the codebase.

Looking forward to the solutions!

Comment: If you know for sure that property is set in a specific function, you could create a different interface for it where endTime is not optional.

Comment: that is a good suggestion! i had not thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your colleagues that you should put the `if` check in place. The reason for this is that your code will be much more robust. Maybe the `endTime` is currently always set, but later on, if the implementation changes on either end, you will still have to keep in mind the decision you have taken and if it's somebody else working on the code, it can easily introduce bugs.

Comment: nice idea about robustness! with this in mind, the additional check makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of undefined values is, what to do when you do not have them? You could simply set a default value using destructuring

```
const {endTime = "00:00"} = getSchedule();
```

In this way, endTime will always be undefined

Or… you could also set defaults values to the entire object

```
const neverNull = {...getSchedule(), {endTime:"00:00"}}
```

Now personally I try to never write to plain objects directly. In your case I would very likely wrap those data into an Adapter as follow:

```
export abstract class AbstractAdapter<T> {
  constructor(protected data: T) {

  }

  public getData(): T {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
class ScheduleAdapter extends AbstractAdapter<ISchedule>{
public getEndTime(): string {
  return this.getData().endTime || this.defaultEndTime();
}

private defaultEndTime():string {
  return "00:00";
}
}
```

usage

```
const schedule = new ScheduleAdapter(getSchedule());
console.log(schedule.getEndTime());
```

Comment: so the idea is to add default values while creating the objects (either through adapters or just writing them directly) and override the default values with actual ones down the road? with this, the interface would not contain optional attributes. each attribute would be required.

Comment: @Hussain yes it’s a way to ensure all the properties at least have a value. Otherwise you can still add a value in the adapter like hasEndTime() returning true if the property of the data is defined. In this manner you have a clean code.

Comment: This is again a good idea to add a property to return true if the data is defined. Thanks for the help! I only just shifted to Typescript a while back so i am learning what the best practices are.